# How to detect browser internal JavaScript errors?

Tags: javascript, browser, filtering, internal, error-logging

We are currently logging all JavaScript errors.
However, some errors seem to be browser internal (plugin, etc) related. Like this one:

> **Error:** Error calling method on NPObject!
>
> **Line:** 0
>
> **Script:** http://www.lookr.com/lookout/1329030315-Giglio-Porto

---

**How is it possible to ignore those browser internal, non-directly-website-related errors?**

---

- Ignoring all errors with `line 0` also seems not appropriate, since inline JavaScript errors would also be ignored (which is not desired)

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: In fact, looks like any plugin-related errors should mention [NPObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NPObject). Have you tried analyzing search errors with `Line: 0` only?

Comment: @raina77ow Yeah, you are probably right. But this would only be FireFox related, right? I want to ignore also browser related errors for other browsers. Actually, I could just ignore all errors with line 0, but I found out, that inline script errors also have line 0, so I would miss those...

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest that you can get ([onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror))

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onerror = function(e) {
            alert('Error');
            console.log(e);
        }
        show('Error'); // show is not defined
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sigh... the type of data the OP gathers _is_ collected with `window.onerror`. And the question is about separating plugin-related errors from all the other ones.

Comment: Yes, the question is not about the gathering, but about the separation :)